# Can't update OS anymore

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

When I was installing an update my computer crashed and shut down. Now, whenever i try to update anything or download an app via the appcenter it asks for permission and then says "Waiting for package manager lock" for a few seconds before automatically canceling the download/update. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it already. Just had to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
```